Time Travel, English Language, Younger and Older version; merging horrificly, Time Law Enforcement, 1990s?
I'm looking for an English language - probably American - action movie.  I would think it's from the mid 1990s to the mid 2000...
It's about a person working in an organization monitoring and policing time travel, and putting right (attempted) changes.  If they see that a change has occurred, someone is sent back to fix the change and apprehend the time traveler who caused it.
One of the rules is that they're not allowed to attempt to contact their younger self - especially not in person.  It's a physical law that the current (ie. past) and the future (ie. time traveling) version of a person can't occupy the same space and time... if they do, they fuse together in horrible - and lethal - ways.
In the movie I'm after, there is a scene where (I think) the hero is about to go back in time, when there is a sudden and unscheduled emergency return of another time-officer.  He has tried to contact himself as a child, and now they both - man and boy - have returned fused together and dying.  Moments later, alarms goes off as multiple time-disturbances - all over both time and space (as in locations on Earth) - as all the people the dead officer ever arrested for time-violations, suddenly never were arrested... because he now had died as a child in the past, long before becoming a time-officer.  The main character is of course (one of the ones?) sent back to fix things.
It's not "Time Cop" (w/Van Damme) - although it applies a similar concept, and a similar scene (with the villain). I guess it could be a sequel (if one exist) to "Time Cop"...
So does this sound familiar to anybody?
PS: I can't absolutely rule out it was a TV-series, but I don't think so.


I guess it could be a sequel (if one exists) to "Time Cop"...

There is...
Timecop 2: The Berlin Decision (2003) with Jason Scott Lee.

In 2025, time travel technology has improved considerably; Time Enforcement Commission (TEC), the agency that monitors time travel, is still keeping the past safe and after the events of the previous film, Society for Historical Authenticity (SHA) is established to ensure that TEC personnel do not alter history.
TEC agent Douglas illegally makes physical contact with his younger self and they are suddenly merged, causing the agent to wink out of existence. Without the agent ever existing, a key Brandon Miller associate wasn't arrested and Miller is able to leave prison on a technicality. Miller sets out to eliminate every TEC operative by traveling back in time and killing their ancestors, as if the agents never existed. Miller could then change history with impunity since there wasn't anyone to stop him. Eventually, Ryan Chang is the only agent left and he has to stop Miller.
Wikipedia

